# Getting information from a Cookie into Alfresco Share

Tags: alfresco

I'm trying to get information from a cookie into Alfresco Share. I have a Filter setup where I can read the cookie, but I'm not sure how to pass that information onto an extension inside of Share or to a piece of code inside of Share that can do something with the information. Does anyone know how to get information from a Cookie into Alfresco Share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone else has this issue, here's what I ended up doing:

1) Read the cookie from inside the filter.

2) Set a session variable:

```
HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession();
session.setAttribute("myLastName", "value from cookie here");
```

3) Read the value from inside the extension:

```
String lastName = (String) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getAttribute("myLastName", RequestAttributes.SCOPE_SESSION);
```

4) Added the following to Tomcat's web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <description>Spring Framework Initilization</description>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Also, it looks like I mis-spoke in my original question, as I the extension existed on the Alfresco layer rather than in the Share layer. However, I assume it'd be the same if your extension existed in the Share layer.

Answer (score 2):

Alfresco Share leverages YUI. Could you use the [YUI Cookie Utility](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/cookie/) to read the cookie? If so, once you do that, you can then do with it what you need, including passing it as an argument to either a repository tier web script or a share tier web script by making an AJAX call.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. I was sort of thinking about it from the server side point of view, since I want to check when a user visits Share, regardless of which page (which is why I have the filter - but I don't know how to get data from the filter to the internals). If I were to do it client side, this would work for most cases I want.